# Android BreakIterator hyphenated words?

Tags: android, regex, textview

I using breakIterator to get each word from a sentence and there is problem when a sentence like "my mother-in-law is coming for a visit" where i am not able to get mother-in-law as a single word.

```
BreakIterator iterator = BreakIterator.getWordInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
for (int end = iterator.next(); end != BreakIterator.DONE; start = end, end = iterator.next()) 
{
        String possibleWord = sentence.substring(start, end);
        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(possibleWord.charAt(0))) 
        {
            // grab the word
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I'm seeing in your code what are you trying to do is to check if the first character in every word are a character or a digit. Every time you use the BreakIterator.getWordInstance() you will always get all the words depending on the boundary rules of the Locale and it is a little hard to accomplish what you want to do with the use of this class until I know, so my advice is this:

```
String text = "my mother-in-law is coming for a visit";
String[] words = text.split(" ");
for (String word : words){
   if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(word.charAt(0))){
      // grab the word
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, your solution is very close it's just that i need to use the start and end position from BreakIterator so that i can set a span on the word. Hmm...